# appending user input with list issue

Tags: python

I'm working on an exercise that involves making a small scaled grocery app using python. Here is the description:

Write a program to keep track of current grocery list and current pantry items. It should ask for the user to ask for which items that they have bought from the grocery list. If they have bought the item, remove the item from grocery list and add the item to list of pantry items.

I have attempted to develop this but the user input is not affecting the list.

```
print("GROCERY LIST APP")
grocerylist = ["Apple", "Onion", "Flour"]
print("You have items in your grocery list:", grocerylist)
updatedgrocerylist = []
itemsinpantry = []

userinput = input("Have you bought Apple?")
userinput2 = input("Have you bought Onion?")
userinput3 = input("Have you brought Flour?")

if userinput == "Yes" or userinput == "yes":
    itemsinpantry.append('Apple')

elif userinput == "No" or userinput == "no":
    updatedgrocerylist.append('Apple')

elif userinput2 == "Yes" or userinput2 == "yes":
    itemsinpantry.append('Onion')

elif userinput2 == "No" or userinput2 == "no":
    updatedgrocerylist.append('Onion')

elif userinput3 == "Yes" or userinput3 == "yes":
    itemsinpantry.append('Flour')

elif userinput3 == "No" or userinput3 == "no":
    updatedgrocerylist.append('Flour')

print("Your updated grocery list:", updatedgrocerylist)
print("Items in the pantry:", itemsinpantry)
```

I expect the program to append the fruits to the list based on user decision.

Comment: What is your input and what output *does* it generate?

Comment: my input is Yes, No, Yes. my output is Your updated grocery list: [], Items in the pantry: ['Apple']. Weird huh? ...

Comment: Your logic is wrong: Instead of if ... elif ... elif... you should use  if ... else/if ...else/if ... else because you can buy apples and onions and flour. Currently you are only checking if you bought apples or not.

Comment: What *excatly* are you typing? Are these `,` and spaces actually in the input? Are you pressing enter at any time? Please clarify.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between if and elif?

Comment: @uneven_mark no the , and spaces are not in the input. I type Yes [ENTER] No [ENTER] Yes [ENTER]

Comment: @mkrieger1 sorry im just starting out on learning to code in python

Comment: @user12012850 Please don't add `(CLOSED)` to your title. You marked an answer as accepted. That is enough of a hint that your problem was resolved. I will suggest another edit to rollback your change. See [this discussion on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the output from Yes, No, Yes is as so, is because of your nested if structuring.
Once the program accepts the first variable "userinput" it will skip the other `elif` statements and go to the two `print` functions at the bottom.
I have provided a possible solution:

```py
print("GROCERY LIST APP")
grocerylist = ["Apple", "Onion", "Flour"]
print("You have items in your grocery list:", grocerylist)
updatedgrocerylist = []
itemsinpantry = []

userinput = input("Have you bought Apple?")
if userinput == "Yes" or userinput == "yes":
    itemsinpantry.append('Apple')
elif userinput == "No" or userinput == "no":
    updatedgrocerylist.append('Apple')

userinput2 = input("Have you bought Onion?")
if userinput2 == "Yes" or userinput2 == "yes":
    itemsinpantry.append('Onion')
elif userinput2 == "No" or userinput2 == "no":
    updatedgrocerylist.append('Onion')

userinput3 = input("Have you brought Flour?")
if userinput3 == "Yes" or userinput3 == "yes":
    itemsinpantry.append('Flour')
elif userinput3 == "No" or userinput3 == "no":
    updatedgrocerylist.append('Flour')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Plus the two `print` at the end ;)

Comment: thank you for the explanation! such a rookie mistake. helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

find corrected code

```
print("GROCERY LIST APP")
grocerylist = ["Apple", "Onion", "Flour"]
print("You have items in your grocery list:", grocerylist)
updatedgrocerylist = []
itemsinpantry = []

userinput = input("Have you bought Apple?")
userinput2 = input("Have you bought Onion?")
userinput3 = input("Have you brought Flour?")

if userinput == "Yes" or userinput == "yes":
    itemsinpantry.append('Apple')

else:
    updatedgrocerylist.append('Apple')

if userinput2 == "Yes" or userinput2 == "yes":
    itemsinpantry.append('Onion')

else:
    updatedgrocerylist.append('Onion')

if userinput3 == "Yes" or userinput3 == "yes":
    itemsinpantry.append('Flour')

else:
    updatedgrocerylist.append('Flour')

print("Your updated grocery list:", updatedgrocerylist)
print("Items in the pantry:", itemsinpantry)
```